# Как сделать в ячейке таблицы Word нижний индекс?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Делаю программную генерацию отчета Word с помощью С#. У меня есть таблица, и в некоторые ячейки надо записать текст, содержащий нижний индекс (причем этот нижний индекс может быть не только цифрой, но и буквой из кириллицы). Например, λ_б (то есть буква б является нижним индексом для лямбды).

В символах Unicode нижних индексов именно для кириллицы не нашел.

Как можно реализовать добавление индексов, пример которых описан выше? Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

P.S. Пользуюсь библиотекой Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, так что желательно какие-то методы оттуда.

Comment: По вашим же ключевым словам у меня ищется такое: [How to add subscript characters in paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12997071/5752652)

Answer (score 1):

Это делается через стиль шрифта. Просто откройте документ в ворде и посмотрите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поиске по ключевым словам типа subscript/superscript находится [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12997071/5752652) пример для interop (там же - для OpenXML версия):

```
using WordNS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

WordNS.Document doc = _application.ActiveDocument;
WordNS.Paragraph p = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
p.Range.Text = "Some text   beff = 3.0";

int start = p.Range.Text.IndexOf("eff");
int end = p.Range.Text.IndexOf("=");

WordNS.Range range = doc.Range(start, end);
range.Select();

WordNS.Selection currentSelection = _application.Selection;
currentSelection.Font.Subscript = 1;

doc.SaveAs2("C:\\SubscriptInterop.docx");
```

Как это сделать в таблице - это уже сами смотрите, принцип тот же: форматирование применяется к параграфу/абзацу внутри ячейки таблицы.